# How to reset the CoreData in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I want to reset all of Swift's CoreData including Entity.
That CoreData already owned the data.
I found another article, it said should delete Entity with Backspace Key.
I did it but I could not deal with it due to an error.
Could you tell me how to initialize CoreData?

Comment: Do you need to clear all the information stored in coreData?

Comment: @AnshadRasheed Yes, I need clear all data.But, I created another CoreData for now.

Comment: you mean you copied the model and created a new persistent store for that?.. i think you can remove the existing entries and reuse the older one.. by using removePersistentStore method u can remove it. and add it again

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468907-removepersistentstore

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just remove any core data initialization and delete the modeld files. Just entail the .xcdatamodeld file and the persistentContainer and saveContext funcs in appDelegate.